# Making an api request using URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an api request:

```
var urlRaw = bookSummaryReadsDomainUrl + apiKey;
let url = URL(string: urlRaw.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error with fetching book summary reads: \(error)")
        return
    }
    
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            print("Error with the response, unexpected status code: \(response)")
            return
    }
    if let data = data,
        let flurryItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode(FlurrySummary.self, from: data) {
        completionHandler(flurryItems.rows ?? [])
    }
})
task.resume()
```

to an endpoint that returns the following data

```
{
"rows": [
{
"dateTime": "2020-07-04 00:00:00.000-07:00",
"event|name": "BookSummaryRead",
"paramName|name": "bookId",
"paramValue|name": "elon-musk",
"count": 12
},
```

...
]

```
import Foundation

struct FlurrySummary: Codable {
    var rows: [FlurryItem]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rows = "rows"
    }
}


struct FlurryItem: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var event: String?
    var value: String?
    var count: String?
    var date: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "paramName|name"
        case event = "event|name"
        case value = "paramValue|name"
        case count = "count"
        case date = "dateTime"
    }
}
```

For some reason the JSONDecoder.decode part is not working. It's not filling up the flurryItems and flurryItems.rows = nil. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: catch the error and print it

Comment: How do you expect to figure out the error ignoring it?

Comment: I’d suggest not using `try?` with the decode, because that discards any diagnostic error, if it failed. Use `do`-`try`-`catch` and see what error you get.

Comment: Btw you are abusing of the optionals. You should declare optional only the properties that might be nil not every property. You should declare your properties as constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `count` in `FlurryItem` has to be of type `Int`.

```
var count: Int?
```

You have to catch the `Error` that are thrown.

```
do {
    if let data = data,
        let flurryItems = try JSONDecoder().decode(FlurrySummary.self, from: data) {
        completionHandler(flurryItems.rows ?? [])
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Also, you don't need the `CodingKeys` in `FlurrySummary` since the property name is the same.

```
struct FlurrySummary: Codable {
    var rows: [FlurryItem]?
}
```

Note: Also, avoid using `optional` declaration if the property never becomes `null`.

Comment: This will fix the error but code only answers are not helpful for future readers.

Comment: Btw does it need to be optional? Does it need to be a variable instead of a constant?

Comment: Are the Coding keys necessary for the root structure?